Fill or complete a hash in ruby with all sibling keys
I have a rails API where I'm able to query vehicles and count and group by different attributes. I would like to fill the response with zero values when a group by is used.
Here is a simple example:
data = {
  AUDI: {
    Petrol: 379,
    Diesel: 326,
    Electric: 447
  },
  TESLA: {
    Electric: 779
  }
}

Since Tesla doesn't have any petrol or diesel cars, then that key isn't even included in the response. I believe this is a consequence of the group_by in postgres, which doesn't include zero counts in the results.
I'm trying to create a function which can "fill" the hash with these missing zero values eg.
fill_hash(data)

should return
data = {
  AUDI: {
    Petrol: 379,
    Diesel: 326,
    Electric: 447
  },
  TESLA: {
    Petrol: 0,
    Diesel: 0,
    Electric: 779
  }
}

This simple case I got working with 3 methods:
def collect_keys(hash, keys = [])
  hash.each do |_, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      keys.concat(value.keys)
      collect_keys(value, keys)
    end
  end
  keys.uniq
end

def fill_missing_keys(hash, all_keys, default_value = 0)
  hash.each do |_, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      all_keys.each do |k|
        value[k] = default_value unless value.key?(k)
      end
      fill_missing_keys(value, all_keys, default_value)
    end
  end
  hash
end

def fill_hash(hash, default_value = 0)
  all_keys = collect_keys(hash)
  fill_missing_keys(hash, all_keys, default_value)
end

# Example usage:
hash = { a: { x: 1 }, b: { y: 1 } }
filled_hash = complete_hash(hash)
puts filled_hash
# Output should be: {:a=>{:x=>1, :y=>0}, :b=>{:y=>1, :x=>0}}

My problem is that the hashes can get more complicated. The simple case only grouped by 2 attributes, but here is an example where we group by 3 attributes.
{
  AUDI: {
    Deregistered: {
      Diesel: 56
    },
    Registered: {
      Petrol: 379,
      Diesel: 270,
      Electric: 447
    }
  },
  TESLA: {
    Registered: {
      Electric: 779
    }
  }
}

My desired output is:
{
  AUDI: {
    Deregistered: {
      Petrol: 0,
      Diesel: 56,
      Electric: 0
    },
    Registered: {
      Petrol: 379,
      Diesel: 270,
      Electric: 447
    }
  },
  TESLA: {
    Deregistered: {
      Petrol: 0,
      Diesel: 0,
      Electric: 0
    },
    Registered: {
      Petrol: 0,
      Diesel: 0,
      Electric: 779
    }
  }
}

Eg. there's keys missing in both last and second to last layer.

If you fill the hash based on the returned data alone, your API response could differ depending on the query. For example, you couldn't properly fill a result that only includes "Tesla" because the additional data would be missing. Maybe it would make more sense to get the keys/attributes from the query or the schema and fill the hash regardless of the returned result.

@engineersmnky You're correct about the depth that if any hash in layer n should all contain the same keys as any other hash in that layer. We can make some assumptions about the data that we will never have a situation where layer n has both hashes and integers as values. If one element has the value of a hash then all "sibling" elements at the same depth would also contain hashes (some just might be missing a few keys, which should be filled from with zeros).

@Stefan That's actually what I want. If you perform the first query and you only filter brands that only produce electric vehicles then I don't want the response to include the diesel or petrol keys. Each element should only contain all unique keys where at least one value is not zero. The main issue that I'm trying to solve is when creating graphs it can be difficult to convert the current api response into x and y series in Google Charts since the number of rows and/or columns might change for each series. This wouldn't be an issue if we added the zero values to the hash.

@TobiasKnudsen for the graphs to be equal, I assume that all keys on any given level should also be ordered identically?

@Stefan That's a good point. The way I'm converting the output from the API to the actual graphs currently handles it in any order as long as the key just exists, but it would be even better if the method could fill the hash and also ensure the same order at any given level. This problem probably isn't Ruby specific - do you know what you would call this transformation? Is it just normalization or does it have a more specific name which can perhaps help me in the right direction?

Here's what I came up with, which seems to satisfy the request, including identical order of keys.
# This will build a "Default" Hash
# for Example: 
# {:AUDI=>{:Petrol=>0, :Diesel=>0, :Electric=>0},
#  :TESLA=>{:Petrol=>0, :Diesel=>0, :Electric=>0}}
def build_default_hash(obj, default_value: 0)
  return obj.transform_values {default_value.dup} unless obj.values.first.is_a?(Hash)
  m = obj.values.reduce(&:deep_merge)
  obj.keys.product([build_default_hash(m, default_value:)]).to_h
end 

# deep_merge the default hash with the existing Hash
def deep_normalize_hash(h, default_value:0) 
  build_default_hash(h, default_value:).deep_merge(h)
end

Usage:(Working Example)
h = {
  AUDI: {
    Deregistered: {
      Diesel: 56
    },
    Registered: {
      Petrol: 379,
      Diesel: 270,
      Electric: 447
    }
  },
  TESLA: {
    Registered: {
      Electric: 779
    }
  }
}
deep_normalize_hash(h)
#=> {:AUDI=>
#     {:Deregistered=>{:Diesel=>56, :Petrol=>0, :Electric=>0},
#      :Registered=>{:Diesel=>270, :Petrol=>379, :Electric=>447}},
#    :TESLA=>
#     {:Deregistered=>{:Diesel=>0, :Petrol=>0, :Electric=>0},
#      :Registered=>{:Diesel=>0, :Petrol=>0, :Electric=>779}}}

You could easily blend this into the Hash class, such that usage could be h.deep_normalize, and while I would generally discourage doing so, given that this is in a rails context no one would even notice a little more core class manipulation.

Very clean implementation and seems to work perfectly!

How about creating a class VehicleCount from which all manufacturers are an instance of, and in the parent set all possible counts to 0?
Class VehicleCount
  attr_accessor :Petrol, :Diesel, :Electric
  def initialize
        @:Petrol = @Diesel = @Electric = 0
    end
end

Class Vehicle
  attr_accessor :Registered, :Deregistered
  def initialize
    @Registered = VehicleCount.new
    @Deregistered = VehicleCount.new
  end
end

Audi = Vehicle.new
Audi.Deregistered.Diesel = 56
Audi.Registered.Petrol = 379
Audi.Registered.Diesel = 270
Audi.Registered.Electric = 447

Something like that.

The code is neither valid nor idiomatic Ruby code.

Thanks for you input! I think your approach could work for this very specific case, but I need a more generic way of handling this since users of my API could group by any attributes in any order. In my example I've grouped by brand and fuel type, but you could group by any of the 60-70 attributes. The question is more an algorithm to "fill" an arbitrary hash with all sibling attributes at n levels. I'll update the question with this clarification.

I've managed to get something working here. The idea is to first create a set of all the unique keys at all levels of the original hash. Then I create a new hash and iterate over the original hash and for each key I make sure it exists in the new hash. I need to do some more testing, but for now this seems to work with any n layers.
module HashHelper
  def fill_hash(hash, default_value = 0)
    keys = collect_keys_at_all_levels(hash)
    create_complete_hash(hash, keys, 0, default_value)
  end

  def collect_keys_at_all_levels(hash, keys = {}, depth = 0)
    keys[depth] ||= Set.new

    hash.each do |key, value|
      keys[depth].add(key)
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        collect_keys_at_all_levels(value, keys, depth + 1)
      end
    end

    keys
  end

  def create_complete_hash(hash, keys, depth = 0, default_value = 0)
    new_hash = {}

    keys[depth].each do |key|
      if hash.key?(key)
        if hash[key].is_a?(Hash)
          new_hash[key] = create_complete_hash(hash[key], keys, depth + 1, default_value)
        else
          new_hash[key] = hash[key]
        end
      else
        if keys[depth + 1]
          new_hash[key] = create_complete_hash({}, keys, depth + 1, default_value)
        else
          new_hash[key] = default_value
        end
      end
    end

    new_hash
  end
end

